# STM32F3 UART receive interrupt data hangs after receveing first set of data from Arduino

Tags: c, uart, interrupt-handling, stm32, arduino-uno

Being beginner in ARM microcontroller, I am using STM32F3 Discovery Kit to communicate with Arduino. I use EWARM for coding and Putty, for serial terminal.

I did an echo test on stm32f3 UART2. The data is displayed on the serial terminal correctly, so I confirmed the uart communication is working as expected.

Then, I try to transfer data from arduino to stm32f3 but the uart on stm32f3 hangs after the first set of data (the first set of data is displayed with correctly with some garbage character included). I have been stuck for quite some time now.

Below is the coding I used for UART. The baudrate is 9600. Can anyone help?

```
#define LINEMAX 15 // Maximal allowed/expected line length

volatile char line_buffer[LINEMAX + 1]; // Holding buffer with space for terminating NUL
volatile int line_valid = 0;

/**
  * @brief  Initialize USART2 for PD6 (USART2_RX) and PD5 (USART2_TX)
  *         used for receiving mouse data from arduino
  * @param  baudrate; by default is 9600
  * @retval None
  * link: http://eliaselectronics.com/stm32f4-usart-example-with-interrupt/
  */
void init_USART2(int baudrate)
{
      USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;    // this is for the GPIO pins used as TX and R
      GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;      // this is for the USART1 initilization
      NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;      // this is used to configure the NVIC (nested vector interrupt controller)

      /* Configure USART1 pins:  Rx and Tx ----------------------------*/
      RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
      GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_6;
      GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
      GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
      GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
      GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
      GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);   

      GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_7);
      GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_7);

      /* Configure USART1 pins:  --------------------------------------*/
      RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART2, ENABLE);

      USART_DeInit(USART2);
      USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = baudrate;
      USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
      USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
      USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
      USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
      USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
      USART_Init(USART2,&USART_InitStructure);

      USART_Cmd(USART2, ENABLE);

      /* Here the USART2 receive interrupt is enabled
       * and the interrupt controller is configured
       * to jump to the USART2_IRQHandler() function
       * if the USART2 receive interrupt occurs
       */
      USART_ITConfig(USART2, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE); // enable the USART2 receive interrupt

      NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART2_IRQn;             // we want to configure the USART1 interrupts
      NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;         // this sets the priority group of the USART1 interrupts
      NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;        // this sets the subpriority inside the group
      NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;           // the USART2 interrupts are globally enabled
      NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);                       // the properties are passed to the NVIC_Init function which takes care of the low level stuff

      // finally this enables the complete USART2 peripheral
      USART_Cmd(USART2, ENABLE);
}

void serial_prints (USART_TypeDef* USARTx, volatile char *buffer)
{
    /* transmit till NULL character is encountered */
    while(*buffer)
    {
      USART_SendData(USARTx, *buffer++);
      while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USARTx, USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
      delay_us(5);
    }
}

void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  static char rx_buffer[LINEMAX];   // Local holding buffer to build line
  static int rx_index = 0;

  if (USART_GetITStatus(USART2, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET) // Received character?
  {
    char rx =  USART_ReceiveData(USART2);

    if ((rx == '\r') || (rx == '\n')) // Is this an end-of-line condition, either will suffice?
    {
        if (rx_index != 0) // Line has some content?
        { 
            memcpy((void *)line_buffer, rx_buffer, rx_index); // Copy to static line buffer from dynamic receive buffer
            line_buffer[rx_index] = 0; // Add terminating NUL
            line_valid = 1; // flag new line valid for processing
            serial_prints(USART2, rx_buffer);    
            rx_index = 0; // Reset content pointer
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (rx_index == LINEMAX) // If overflows pull back to start
            rx_index = 0;

          rx_buffer[rx_index++] = rx; // Copy to buffer and increment
    }
  }
}
```

For arduino, I use the following code and the data is displayed correctly in the serial terminal:

```
printf("%d, %d \n", X, Y);
```

Answer (score 2):

You add the terminating null character to `line_buffer`, but then you pass `rx_buffer` to the function `serial_prints`:

```
line_buffer[rx_index] = 0; // Add terminating NUL
line_valid = 1; // flag new line valid for processing
serial_prints(USART2, rx_buffer);    
rx_index = 0; // Reset content pointer
```

This has the consequence that you will iterate past the length of `buffer` in the function `serial_prints` because `buffer` will not be null terminated:

```
while(*buffer)
{
  USART_SendData(USARTx, *buffer++);
  while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USARTx, USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
  delay_us(5);
}
```

On a side-node, you should also use interrupts to send your characters (TX Empty interrupts). Actively waiting in the interrupt service routine for UART characters to be sent will considerably slow-down your program.